# What's wrong with the following implementation of the Knapsack stuffing algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, knapsack-problem

**Edit2:** Now fails for test({64, 1, 36, 81}, 82)
**Edit1:** Now updated to fix problems because of delta > max(items)
**Edit0:** Now updated to fix the infinite recursion due to oscillating delta problem.

---

In [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gSyDMtdPNpU) algorithms video (at around 2:52) Prof. Skiena specifies the knapsack problem as follows...

**The Knapsack problem:** Given a set of integers S = {s1, s2,..., sN} and given a target number T find a subset of S which adds up **exactly** to T.

Then he goes on to say that this is one of those problems for which no known efficient solution exists!

But I tried anyway and here is my attempt at a solution (and it seems to work for the numbers I have tried)...

```
from itertools import accumulate

#items   - All available items
#target  - The size of the knapsack
#returns - A subset of {items} whose sum adds upto target
#          if possible else returns None
def KnapsackItems(items, target):
    s = sum(items)
    if s < target:
        return None
    delta = s - target

    if delta == 0:
        return items

    if delta in items:
        result = items - {delta}
        return result

    if delta > max(items):
        sortedItems = list(sorted(items))
        deltas = list(map(lambda x: x - target, accumulate(sortedItems)))
        ul = [i for i,d in zip(sortedItems, deltas) if d <= i]
        return KnapsackItems(set(ul), target)
    else:
        U = {i for i in items if i < delta}

    V = KnapsackItems(U, delta)
    if V:
        result = items - V
        return result
    return None
```

And here is the test harness...

```
def test(items, target):
    print("Items:", items)
    print("Target:", target)

    result = KnapsackItems(items, target)

    if result and not sum(result) == target:
        print("Result:", result)
        print("FAIL: sum of returned set does not match target ({})".format(target))
    elif result:
        print("Result:", result)
        print("Success (sum of returned set:{})".format(sum(result)))
    else:
        print("No solution could be found")
```

Examples from the video...

```
test({1,2,5,9,10}, 22)
test({1,2,5,9,10}, 23) #No solution expected
test({1,2,3,4,5}, 11)
test({1,2}, 2)
test({4,3,2}, 5)
test({1, 3, 4, 7, 9}, 13)
test({6,7,8,3,14,5,15,2,4}, 29)
test({1,2,3,4,5,6,7},14)
test({64, 1, 36, 81}, 82)
```

Result...

```
Items: {9, 10, 2, 5, 1}
Target: 22
Result: {9, 10, 2, 1}
Success (sum of returned set:22)

Items: {9, 10, 2, 5, 1}
Target: 23
No solution could be found

Items: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Target: 11
Result: {1, 2, 3, 5}
Success (sum of returned set:11)

Items: {1, 2}
Target: 2
Result: {2}
Success (sum of returned set:2)

Items: {2, 3, 4}
Target: 5
Result: {2, 3}
Success (sum of returned set:5)

Items: {9, 3, 4, 1, 7}
Target: 13
Result: {9, 4}
Success (sum of returned set:13)

Items: {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 14, 15}
Target: 29
Result: {14, 15}
Success (sum of returned set:29)

Items: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}
Target: 14
Result: {2, 5, 7}
Success (sum of returned set:14)

Items: {64, 81, 36, 1}
Target: 82
No solution could be found
```

So now I guess the question is what is wrong with my solution to the knapsack problem? Is it inefficient and unusable for very large sets of numbers? Also please let me know if this is not the right place for such questions.

Comment: Might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: KnapsackItems({1, 3, 5}, 9) gives a stack overflow error

Comment: So does KnapsackItems({1, 3, 4, 7, 9}, 13)

Comment: @sanity nice catch! Let me see if I can fix this.

Comment: I suspect the core issue here is that there needs to be a way for the algorithm to "backtrack", ie. try something, but then go back and try something else.

Comment: I think none of your "positive solution" example test cases ever get to the recursive step.

Comment: KnapsackItems({1, 3, 5}, 9) fails because delta is zero here I need to return items as it is in this case.

Comment: I'm not skilled enough to analyze the code, but I would like to point out that this is not actually the knapsack problem, but the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is an easier version. According to Wikipedia, it is still only NP-complete, which means no efficient (polynomial) algorithm is known.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal try test({1,2,3}, 2)

Comment: @sanity Delta oscillates between 13 and 11 for KnapsackItems({1, 3, 4, 7, 9}, 13). Need to see if this is fatal.

Comment: @sanity I have a solution for KnapsackItems({1, 3, 4, 7, 9}, 13).

Answer (score 2):

When `max(items) < target < sum - max(items)` (I don't know Python) then `delta` will always be more than `max(items)` and no items will ever be removed before the recursive check, and the algorithm will never terminate.

Edited version:

It now fails when `max(items)` cannot be part of the solution (such as when `max(items) > target`) and `max(items) < delta`. Example: `{2, 3, 4, 6}, 5`. After the first iteration, it becomes `{2, 3, 4}, 10`, which returns `None`, causing the top level call to return `None`, which is incorrect.

Comment: Actually in the first step, no of item shall be removed. But will it be true for successive steps as well? Because delta is changing at each step.

Comment: @KendallFrey Yup this seems to be the problem with the example given by sanity. KnapsackItems({1, 3, 4, 7, 9}, 13). May be this is a fatal flaw (or may be not) let me see if I can work this out. Delta oscillates between 13 and 11 in this case.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Yes, when this is true for the first step, it will be true for future steps as well.

Comment: @KendallFrey Aah yes I see, then delta will oscillate.

Comment: @KendallFrey please see updated solution. Does it fix your problem?

Comment: @KendallFrey Oops I need to think this through. Will get back to you with a solution if possible.

Comment: @SandeepDatta If you manage to solve this in polynomial time, you will be a very, very, famous person. You'll have to think pretty hard. :)

Comment: @KendallFrey hahaha. I know I just want to put in some more effort to develop an understanding of why this is such a hard problem.

Comment: @KendallFrey it seems (like you said) when delta > max(items) there is no reduction in the problem size and probably this is why a polynomial time solution is not possible.

Comment: @KendallFrey fixed KnapsackItems({2, 3, 4, 6}, 5) :)

Comment: I can't be bothered to debug your code all day, so I think I'll leave it as is.

Answer (score 1):

```
KnapsackItems({6,7,8,3,14,5,15,2,4}, 29)

  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 95, in KnapsackItems
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 4.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 95, in <setcomp>
builtins.RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth excee
```

Apparently 1 million dollar question is not that easy to solve :)

Answer (score 1):

There are chances of infinite recursion, like the following data set.

```
For example,
{(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),14}
sum = 28.
delta = 14.
```

So if `sum = 2 * target`, and `max(items) < target` then it will cause infinite recursion.

Comment: I think the main issue with this answer is that the OP is right. If any single item larger than the delta is not in the solution, the remaining items must sum to less than the target, and thus the solution is not a solution.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I have fixed this problem.